# SDL event loop quitting?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl

I am making an RTS in C++ using SDL for graphics.

Every time I run the game, it crashes without errors or anything in the compiler debug window.  It doesn't crash immediately or consistently, sometimes taking 10 seconds to crash and other times taking 2 minutes to crash.

When I played around with return values (at the end of the main function) it turned out it wasn't crashing, but rather quitting as the return values were consistent with what I changed it to.

The only theory that I have is that my poll event loop is glitching and telling the program to quit when it isn't supposed to.

Here is my event loop, contained within my game loop:

```
    if( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
    {
        if( event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION )
        {
            mx = event.motion.x;
            my = event.motion.y;
        }

        if( event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN )
        {
            if( hut.getselected() && hut.getplacable() )
            {
                hut.place( map );
            }
        }

        if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
        {
            quit = true;
        }

        switch( event.key.keysym.sym )
        {
        case SDLK_ESCAPE: quit = true; break;
        }
    }
```

Is it possible that when the mouse moves or clicks, that it is confusing it for exiting?  I don't think the ram is overloading either because it only displays what it needs to tile-wise.

Is it also possible that my compiler, VisualC++, is screwing up?

Comment: I think it's ok. Not really problem in your code. We need more code. If you think is if confusing (if else if is your friend) and use debug with printf or write or another for see in which if enter

Comment: set breakpoint in your `if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )` and see if you really gets SDL_QUIT message

Comment: I guess you may be overflowing a buffer or something in the stack, deep in your function call graph, and the event struct gets corrupted. Sometimes, by chance, the `event.type` happens to get the value `SDL_QUIT` and the program exits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about changing the switch at end of your snippet to:

```
if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
    quit = true;
}
```

Because in your code you check keysym for all events, so usually event is of wrong type when you test if it is escape, and you get "garbage" value for keysym, and sometimes it matches with ESC.

---

Actually might be good idea to test the `event.type` with switch:

```
switch(event.type) {
case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
    //....
    break;
case SDK_KEYDOWN:
    switch(event.key.keysym.sym) {
    case SDLK_ESCAPE: 
        quit = true;
        break;
    // cases for other keypresses
    }
    break;
// cases for other events
}
```

Comment: Yes as it turns out, after setting up some breakpoints the escape key was triggering without me pressing it!  All I need to do now is adjust it so that the escape key is checked more carefully.

Comment: Keep in mind that the SDL_Event is a union (all of the values share the same space as each other) and the reason that checking for SDL_KEYDOWN first works is because it's specifically looking for keyboard events and not anything that looks like a SDLK_ESCAPE key.  Any type of event that has the same value as the Escape key would trigger your code to quit.